# Xamarin warning BG8102 has unknown base type when adding Citizen printer jar

Tags: xamarin, printing, jar, binding

I'm using Xamarin forms to build an app that prints some content with a citizen printer.
In order to do so I downloaded the printer [jar](http://www.citizen-systems.co.jp/english/support/download/printer/sdk/index.html) and created a Bindings Library to use the jar in my project.

But I get this warning **BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8102: Class Com.Citizen.Sdk.ESCPOSPrinter has unknown base type com.citizen.csjposlib.c.c.**

And I'm not hable to access the classes I need.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Hi did you find any solution?